# Spring nullable annotation generates unknown enum constant warning

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my app, whenever I add `@Nullable` (which imports from `org.springframework.lang.Nullable`) to any of the fields, I get a build warning:

> Warning:java: unknown enum constant javax.annotation.meta.When.MAYBE
>     reason: class file for javax.annotation.meta.When not found

`@NonNull` and other null safety annoations from spring compile without any warnings as its implementation doesn't import `import javax.annotation.meta.When`.

The application runs just fine but the warning is just annoying. I am using spring boot `2.1.0` and java version `1.8.0_191`

Comment: See this question and in particular, the comment on its answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104667/java-compilation-error-using-findbugs-com-sun-tools-javac-code-symbolcompletio

Comment: This gave me an issue whenever I ran embedded Tomcat, but standalone it did not give me an issue.  I just removed the problem annotations.

Answer (score 67):

This warning is caused by the `javax.annotation.meta.When` enum not being available to your projects runtime (`org.springframework.lang.Nullable` references this enum but it is not made available automatically).  You need to bring in a JSR305 implementation to fix this warning.

the Google find bugs repo includes a JSR305 implementation that should fix the problem:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305

since you are using gradle, add the dependency to your `build.gradle` script:

```
...
dependencies {
    ...

     // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'

    ...
}
...
```

*do a clean build and the error should go away*

---

If you do not want to use the `com.google.code.findbugs` group's artifact you can try another from this list:
https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=JSR305

references:

- [Strange Eclipse IDE error javax.annotation.meta.When #Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651366/strange-eclipse-ide-error-javax-annotation-meta-when-java)
- [What happened to Java's @OverridingMethodMustCallSuper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448027/what-happened-to-javas-overridingmethodmustcallsuper/8448084#8448084)
- https://github.com/sbrannen/runtime-annotations/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/SpringApplication.java

Comment: It helps for gradle + IntelliJ IDEA, so thanks for the advice.

Comment: Had the same problem with SB 2.3.6.RELEASE after adding a HandlerInterceptorAdapter. Same solution applies.Tks.

Comment: compileOnly 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2' is enough

Comment: It helps with warnings, but produces “No processor claimed any of these annotations” (lots of Spring & JPA annotations).

Comment: For a Spring Boot starter, if you are using its BOM, you can omit the version and just write:

```<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>```

Answer (score 15):

it's bothered me too.
just try this in your pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

it's work for me.

Comment: Problem still exists even after adding this dependency. I'm using Gradle, but it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Note: This artifact was moved to:

com.github.spotbugs » spotbugs-annotations

Comment: This worked for me in my POM

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spotbugs-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>