# Solr 7 with Spring data and basic authentication not working

Tags: solr, spring-data

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDataSolarApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringDataSolarApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
SolrTemplate solrTemplate() {
  return new SolrTemplate(solrClientFactory());
}

@Bean
SolrClientFactory solrClientFactory() {
  Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("solr", "SolrRocks");
  return new HttpSolrClientFactory(solrClient(), credentials , "BASIC");
}

@Bean
SolrClient solrClient() {

  return new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr").build();
}
```

}

public interface EmployeeRepository extends SolrCrudRepository{

```
Employee findByName(String name);
```

}

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeRepository repository;

@PostConstruct
public void addEmployees() {
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    employees.add(new Employee("373", "Basant", new String[] { "Bangalore", "BTM" }));
    employees.add(new Employee("908", "Santosh", new String[] { "Hyderbad", "XYZ" }));
    employees.add(new Employee("321", "Sagar", new String[] { "Pune", "PQR" }));
    repository.saveAll(employees);

}

@GetMapping("/getALL")
public Iterable<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return repository.findAll();
}

@GetMapping("/getEmployee/{name}")
public Employee getEmployeeByName(@PathVariable String name) {
    return repository.findByName(name);
}
```

}

the getALL operation is working fine but the save operation failed with this error. Please help

Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity.
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:225) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar:4.5.7]
    ... 63 common frames omitted

Comment: I have no problem using Solrj to query and update solr collection with Basic Authentication                                                                            
    List<SolrInputDocument> docs = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
 
   UpdateRequest req = new UpdateRequest();
   
   req.add(docs);
   req.setBasicAuthCredentials("solr", "SolrRocks");
 
   UpdateResponse rsp = req.process(solrClient, "employee");
   req.commit(solrClient, "employee");

Answer (score 3):

Came across same issue and solved with extending `HttpSolrClient` and applying same backend approach with recommended way mentioned on [Solr docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/basic-authentication-plugin.html#using-basic-auth-with-solrj) but getting credentials from constructor not setting on each request.

```java
class CustomSolrClient extends HttpSolrClient {
    @Nullable
    private final String username;
    @Nullable
    private final String password;

    CustomSolrClient(Builder builder, String username, String password) {
        super(builder);
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public NamedList<Object> request(SolrRequest request, ResponseParser processor, String collection) throws SolrServerException, IOException {
        HttpRequestBase method = createMethod(request, collection);
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            String userPass = username + ":" + password;
            String encoded = Base64.byteArrayToBase64(userPass.getBytes(UTF_8));
            method.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded));
        }
        return executeMethod(method, processor, request instanceof V2Request || request.getPath().contains("/____v2"));
    }
}
```

And create bean using that:

```java
    @Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient() {
        return new CustomSolrClient(new HttpSolrClient.Builder(properties.getHost()), properties.getUsername(), properties.getPassword());
    }
```

This may seem as an ugly approach but if you check `HttpSolrClientFactory` [sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/blob/4.0.6.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/solr/server/support/HttpSolrClientFactory.java#L76) it's even more uglier which actually accesses private field of `HttpClient` belongs to Solr client.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. Just a quick comment may be you should add a note where did you introduce `UTF_8` constant? And `@Nullable` throws [this annoying warning] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326271/spring-nullable-annotation-generates-unknown-enum-constant-warning). Did you fix that? Do you know why we need it?

Comment: @AlexanderNikiforov Well I pasted this from original implementation to give idea. On my own implementation I was using internal libraries but you can copy it from `HttpSolrClient` and put in your class. `javax.annotation.Nullable`s are not really relevant, just ruleset on our codebase to assist IDE etc.